# Android Webview - Is it creating multiple instances?

Tags: android, webview

I am wondering if there are are multiple instances of webview being created in my Android App. If yes how do I solve it?

Reason for my confusion is that I am seeing this in my Chrome Developer Tools.
[image: Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot]

Whenever I am calling loadURL, I am seeing a new line item on Chrome as if if there is a new instance of WebView being created.
and here's my Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
        { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
    }
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // Page is done loading;
            _appRunning = true;
        }
    });
    myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

    myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    myWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);

    final WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath(f.getAbsolutePath());
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

  }
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if(!checkConnectivity()) return;
        _appRunning = true;
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String url = getString(R.string.app_url);

        myWebView.loadUrl(url);
        myWebView.onResume();
        hideSystemUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
        stopPlayer();
        //myWebView.onPause();            
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        stopPlayer();
        super.onStop();
    }

    private void stopPlayer(){
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
        showSystemUI();
        _appRunning = false;
    }
```

Comment: There are cases where the onResume() method is called multiple times so that might cause the issue. I suggest putting this line WebView 
        myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        String url = getString(R.string.app_url);
in onCreate() method of your code

Comment: I have that in onCreate() too. The behavior I am seeing is when user press home button and launch the app again. Every time the app is launched, pretty much it is showing up as a new line on Chrome developer tools.

Comment: It looks like every time App is invoked using an intent, it is creating a new Instance of the activity. Calling finish() method in the onStop() and onResume() methods solved this problem. I am still trying to find a better solution though as I really want to keep and reuse the instance of the activity to perform certain background operations, while app is int he background.

Answer (score 1):

Do not redeclare WebView in your stopPlayer() and onResume(). Use the same instance you have created in onCreate(). 
You can define that webView as a field and initialise it in onCreate() and use it everywhere.

```
WebView myWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);        

myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    if (0 != (getApplicationInfo().flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_DEBUGGABLE))
    { WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true); }
}
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // Page is done loading;
        _appRunning = true;
    }
});
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

myWebView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
myWebView.getSettings().setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_COMPATIBILITY_MODE);

final WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();

webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAppCachePath(f.getAbsolutePath());
webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(!checkConnectivity()) return;
    _appRunning = true;
    String url = getString(R.string.app_url);

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
    myWebView.onResume();
    hideSystemUI();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();  // Always call the superclass method first
    stopPlayer();
    //myWebView.onPause();            
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    stopPlayer();
    super.onStop();
}

private void stopPlayer(){

    myWebView.loadUrl("about:blank");
    showSystemUI();
    _appRunning = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Shriyansh. I tried that... didn't make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, configChanges triggered in my app causing the onCreate event run mulitple times. adding following code in your activity:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.d("chessnutActivity","onConfigurationChanged");
    }
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity
            ...
            android:configChanges="screenLayout|smallestScreenSize|screenSize|touchscreen|layoutDirection|orientation"
            ...>
            ...
        </activity>
```

by this way it solved most of my problem.